# How to set progress spinner while loading image online?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

In my app , I load an image from a url using `AsyncTask` , while the image loads , the `ImageView` is empty . So , while its loading , how can i display a spinner/loading progress there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample code:

```
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  private ProgressDialog progressdialog;

 @Override
protected void onPreExecute(){ 
   super.onPreExecute();
        progressdialog= new ProgressDialog(yourContext);
        progressdialog.setMessage("Downloading Image");
        progressdialog.show();    
}

@Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   //Do whatever you have to here
  }


  @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
   super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressdialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: it causes my app to crash !

Comment: Can you put more of the logcat? I can't identify where it's crashing... Have you put the context correctly?

Comment: i did getApplicationContext() for that